# Spring Websocket between anonymous user and authenticated user

Tags: spring, grails, spring-websocket

i am trying to create a chat feature where this chatting happen between anonymous user and authenticated user. like `Zopin` or `tawk.io`.

i tried to create/study from [this link](https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket) and it i already know how to send to a user with `/user/topic/hello`

but this happen between two authenticated users.

how about between anonymous user and authenticated user?

i already success send message from `anonymous user` to `users who have logged in`

for example , i am loginning with user `abc001`.
then `anonymous` user send messaget to `abc001` with :

`client.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify("hi, i am anonymous user"));`

but how user `abc001`to reply this `anonymous user`?

Comment: He may be anonymous user, but he still needs to be an identified instance in your app. Assign an internal id so you can reference him...

Comment: how? how can i identify that user? `client.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify("place username here?"));` @Al-Punk

Comment: @Al-Punk please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367105/spring-websocket-get-access-to-cookie-in-config/41367849#41367849). I guess it may be helpful for you.